# .NET Framework 4.8 seems to use C# version older than 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c#-7.0, .net-4.8

It seems like I have got problems with vs not handing inline var declarations.

It turns out that is uses an old version of c#.

Here comes a screenshot that shows that `out string link` is not compiling.

[image: calling]

I add the source without screenshot as well

```
if (foo(appid, webuid, out string link))
{
  result.Body += link;
}
```

The function I am calling has the signature

```
public static bool foo(string appid, string baz, out string link)
{
  /* code */
}
```

Why is an older C# version used by vs?

In my project, I have selected .NET Framework 4.8 as target.

[image: Selecting target framwork]

The error message reads

> Error CS8059  Feature 'out variable declaration' is not available in C#
> 6. Please use language version 7.0 or greater.

Comment: What language version are you using? It must be C# 6.0 and that feature is not available in C# 6.0.

Comment: Check the project file content for `LangVersion`.

Comment: .NET and C# are two different things. You need C# 7. It does not matter which .NET Framework is being targeted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a comment to formulate the answer. I checked the csproj file and searched for `LangVersion`.

```
<LangVersion>6</LangVersion>
```

Removing the line solved the problem.

The language version nowadays is based on the .NET framework version and is not separately specified.

You cannot set the language version in the projects advanced properties, but the setting seems to be respected despite that.